# INSERT with GROUP BY in VALUE SELECT Statement - ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-insert, insert-into

I am trying to count distinct values after Grouping by id then inserting them into another table with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table_aggregate
  (id_aggregate, aggregate_column)
(SELECT id_detail, COUNT(DISTINCT(detail_column))
  FROM table_detail
  GROUP BY id_detail)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  aggregate_column = COUNT(DISTINCT(detail_column));
```

When run I get the error:

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

If I run the SELECT statement portion of the query it works fine. Why is it throwing this error?

Comment: Do you want to know why it's throwing an error, or do you want to construct a functioning query? If the latter, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Try `VALUES(aggregate_column)` in the UPDATE part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `COUNT` in the UPDATE part. Use `VALUES(aggregate_column)` instead:

```
INSERT INTO table_aggregate
  (id_aggregate, aggregate_column)
(SELECT id_detail, COUNT(DISTINCT(detail_column))
  FROM table_detail
  GROUP BY id_detail)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  aggregate_column = VALUES(aggregate_column);
```

http://rextester.com/KTEDM89215

Answer (score 1):

You can put the aggregation inside a subquery. Then you can refer to the computed value in the `update`

```
INSERT INTO
    table_aggregate (id_aggregate, aggregate_column) 
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                id_detail,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(detail_column)) AS count 
            FROM
                table_detail 
            GROUP BY
                id_detail 
        ) AS aggr 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE
    aggregate_column = aggr.count
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see this would've worked, but the other answer was more concise as there was no need to create a second SELECT statement.